# mails through amtp using zend mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, zend-mail

Can someone please suggest me from where to download zend framework and the codes for sending mails using gmail smtp and zend in php?? please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to download Zend Framework from: http://www.zend.com/community/downloads

You will send an email like this:

```
<?php 
$options = array(
        'auth'     => 'login',
        'username' => '_username_@gmail.com',
        'password' => '_password_',
        'ssl'      => 'tls',
        'port' => 587
    );
    $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $options);
    Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);

    $m = new Zend_Mail();
    $m->addTo('someone@gmail.com');
    $m->setFrom('_username_@gmail.com', 'Sender name');
    $m->setSubject('Using Gmail SMTP');
    $m->setBodyText('Hello! I am using Gmail from the localhost :)');
    $m->send();
```